# How to Add Text after a PHP variable

Tags: php

I have a variable named "$autovalue" . My another variable called $row1 and I want it to contain the value of "$autovalue" with a "_1" so that when I echo the $row1 it looks like this: 2011_1 (here 2011 is the value of $autovalue and " _1 " is what I want to include). I tried the following method but it is not working.

Could you please tell me how to achieve this ?

Thanks in Advance :)

```
   $autovalue=mysql_insert_id();

    $row1=$autovalue.""._1;
    $row2=$autovalue.""._2;
    $row3=$autovalue.""._3;
    $row4=$autovalue.""._4;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$row1 = $autovalue . "_1";
$row2 = $autovalue . "_2";
$row3 = $autovalue . "_3";
$row4 = $autovalue . "_4";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also add texts by this way :

```
$text = '12';

$text .= '34';
$text .= '56';
$text .= '78';

echo $text;
```

the result will be : 12345678

Answer (score 1):

```
$row1 = $autovalue."_".1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally preferred:

```php
$row1 = sprintf( '%s_1', $autovalue );
```

See [the manual's page about sprintf](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php) for further information.